# code=exited, status=1/FAILURE on mkfs.ext4 in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mount, ext4, systemctl

I stopped this service and now when I attempt to start it I get the following error:

Is there a way I can find out why the first process is failing?

```
systemctl status crmpicco-admin.service
● crmpicco-admin.service - CRMPicco Boot Script
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/crmpicco-admin.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-06-20 16:59:09 AWST; 17s ago
    Process: 57047 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c /usr/sbin/mkfs.ext4 -L crmpicco-admin /dev/nvme1n1 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Process: 57048 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c mkdir -p /var/lib/crmpicco-admin (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 57049 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c mountpoint -q /var/lib/localcache || mount /var/lib/localcache (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 57051 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c mkdir -p /var/lib/localcache/cache /var/lib/localcache/ini /var/lib/localcache/sites (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 57052 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c mountpoint -q /var/lib/crmpicco-admin || mount /var/lib/provision (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 57054 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c mkdir -p /var/lib/crmpicco-admin/tmp (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 57055 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/crmpicco-admin/tmp (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 57060 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c ln -f -s /var/lib/crmpicco-admin/tmp /var/lib/localcache/tmp (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 57060 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 20 16:59:08 ip-10-80-32-115 systemd[1]: Starting CRMPicco Boot Script...
Jun 20 16:59:09 ip-10-80-32-115 systemd[1]: crmpicco-admin.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 20 16:59:09 ip-10-80-32-115 systemd[1]: crmpicco-admin.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 20 16:59:09 ip-10-80-32-115 systemd[1]: Failed to start CRMPicco Boot Script.
```

Comment: Is the disk mounted correctly?

Comment: What's the best way to check?

Comment: Do you notice any errors in the booting process? if not you're OK.

Comment: Not that I could see. I killed the instance and spun up a fresh instance and that "fixed" it, for now. However, i'd like to understand why it failed and remedy for it for the next time that I need to stop and restart this service. Is there somewhere I can see the error messages behind this failure? `code=exited, status=1/FAILURE` doesn't give much away.

Answer (score 1):

All service output goes to the *journal* (syslog); see `journalctl [-f] [-n 100] [-b]`.

Most likely the service fails because mkfs.ext4 refuses to create a new filesystem on a device which *already contains* a filesystem.